# Firebase data sorting by timestamp

Tags: sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase node structure like the following.

```
categories
    category1
        timestamps
            23c491sdfwrasddgasd: true
            asdf8234dfjalskdask: true
            39fsdizxcasfgbskdf7: true
            2asqwizxov340bs9fms: true
    category2
        timestamps
            p23491sdfwrasddgasd: true
            asdfpovaskdrfskdask: true
    category3
        timestamps
            vmk339ffk3rasddgasd: true
            asdf8234dfjalskdvml: true
            bnwdwizxcasfgbskdf7: true
```

The timestamp keys are the keys generated by `push()`. I need to sort the categories by the oldest timestamp key they have. Only the oldest timestamp from the timestamps node will count.

Basically I need to sort the categories by the time they were modified for the first time.

Any help is welcome including tips to redesign the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought about flatting your Database?
Change your Database Design to:

categories

```
  category1
    oldest_timestamp: 2asqwizxov340bs9fms
    timestamps
        23c491sdfwrasddgasd: true
        asdf8234dfjalskdask: true
        39fsdizxcasfgbskdf7: true
        2asqwizxov340bs9fms: true
  category2
    oldest_timestamp: asdfpovaskdrfskdask
    timestamps
        p23491sdfwrasddgasd: true
        asdfpovaskdrfskdask: true
  category3
    oldest_timestamp: bnwdwizxcasfgbskdf7
    timestamps
        vmk339ffk3rasddgasd: true
        asdf8234dfjalskdvml: true
        bnwdwizxcasfgbskdf7: true
```

Basically you have added a node called "oldest_timestamp". Now you can easily order your categories with a query.

```
Query myquery =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("categories").orderByChild("oldest_timestamp");
```

Don't forget to index that in your Firebase Database Rules for better Performance.

Comment: Currently I push a value every time I modify the category. How can I detect if the category has been modified already? Do I have to check the category first using a value listener?

Comment: Yes you can do this with a ValueEventListener and using dataSnapshot.exists() at the timestamp location. But it's hard to tell because I don't know the whole context of the App